# Why is Perl Net::LDAP with GSSAPI SASL bind connecting with wrong sasl_ssf on Debian buster?

Tags: perl, openldap, sasl, gssapi, debian-buster

I have a Perl script to read from an OpenLDAP instance using Net::LDAP with a GSSAPI bind. The script works fine on Debian stretch but *fails* on Debian buster.

Note that on both servers the line at the bottom of the Perl code that runs `ldapsearch` produces the same correct results, so I am sure that the Kerberos ticket cache is correct on both servers.

Looking at the OpenLDAP logs I see that the ldapsearch run shows up with the strength factors `sasl_ssf=256 ssf=256` while the Net::LDAP bind shows up with the strength factors `sasl_ssf=1 ssf=256`. Since the Net::LDAP bind is using Kerberos, the `sasl_ssf` should be 56, not 1.

Any suggestions as to why the Net::LDAP bind is connecting with the wrong `sasl_ssf`?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Authen::SASL;
use Net::LDAP;
use Data::Dumper;

my $server_name = 'ldap.example.com';
$ENV{'KRB5CCNAME'} = '/tmp/krb.tkt';

my $ld = Net::LDAP->new($server_name, version => '3');
$ld->start_tls(verify => 'require');

if (!$ld or $ld == -1) {
    die "Could not connect to directory server $server_name";
}

my $SASL = Authen::SASL->new('GSSAPI');
my $status = $ld->bind(sasl => $SASL);

if ($status->code) {
    die  'Bind error: (' . $status->error_name . ') ' . $status->error_text;
}

my $base   = 'dc=example,dc=com';
my $filter = '(uid=johndoe)';
my @attrs  = ('uid', 'sn');
$status = $ld->search(
    base    => 'dc=example,dc=com',
    filter  => $filter,
    attrs   => \@attrs,
    ) ;

my @entries = $status->all_entries;
# This results in nothing (but should result in the same data as the ldapsearch below):                                                                                                          
warn Dumper @entries ;

my $attrs = join(' ', @attrs) ;
my $cmd = "ldapsearch -LLL -h $server_name -b $base '$filter' $attrs";
# This gives the correct result:                                                                                                     
warn `$cmd`;
```